# User level in robridge

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I would like to know how to assigned authorization to None-ROS client, like a browser, which is connected through rosbridge.
If I am right, I can realize it by using the 'level' field in rosbridge.
(Otherwise what is it used for?)

I read the protocol document, but I couldn't get the answer.

Isn't it implemented?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224899/user-level-in-robridge/) by [Lain Iwakura](https://answers.ros.org/users/25630/lain-iwakura/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default there is no authentication enabled in rosbridge so any browser can connect. You can enable only authorized clients to connect by using rosauth (see [GitHub](https://github.com/WPI-RAIL/rosauth) for source code and [this paper](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/%7Ecshue/research/tepra14.pdf) for details). The current implementation only checks for authentication, not authorization (i.e., different user levels). Although a field is passed along indicating the user lever specified from the client. This could be extended of course.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2016-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lain Iwakura](https://answers.ros.org/users/25630/lain-iwakura/) on 2016-01-31**:
Thank you for your answer. I read your answer. I would like to implement the authorization part if I have the chance..